# Why does AWS have two services to deploy Docker (one "Infra" and one "Platform")?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

When I look at the AWS product summary here:

http://aws.amazon.com/

There is an "Infra" offering called EC2 Container Service:

http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/

There is also a "Plaform" offering called Elastic Beanstalk (w/ Docker support):

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Why does AWS have two ways to deploy Docker and why are they across both the Infra. and Platform categories?

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk is a platform as a service. It runs applications using a variety of techniques, including docker containers. It is meant to be simpler than managing your own instances and networks, but the trade off is less control over how the environment is run.

EC2 Container Service is an infrastructure as a service. It is an API that exposes a few primitives for managing Docker containers on clusters of EC2 instances. The user has more ability to manage the systems and network in which the application runs, but assumes more responsibility for operating the environment. Also, it is still a very early product and some basic features are still being developed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon for AWS to have more than one way to do things. A similar continuum can be seen with beanstalk-opsworks-cloudformation or the various database offerings.

Elastic Beanstalk is a "platform" play because it is designed to let a developer ignore the details of running their own infrastructure. It competes with Heroku in that way.

Elastic Container Service (in beta, and woefully lacking in features) is a building block in the same way that S3, EC2, RDS are building blocks. There's a lot more platform-building required of the customer, but it gives much finer control.